# How to read SVM results graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, svm

As part of my academic project regarding predicting success rate of an upcoming movie, I had to use SVM classifier for multiple classes in order to classify to which class a movie belong. There are 5 classes :

```
Class 1 - Revenue < 0.5M
Class 2 - 0.5M < Revenue < 1M
Class 3 - 1M < Revenue < 50M
Class 4 - 50M < Revenue < 150M
Class 5 - Revenue > 150M
```

I get the results, and I'm able to calculate accuracy, but I have no idea how to read the following graph :

[image]

Can someone please explain, what do we see in this graph? How should I read it?

Comment: Sorry but this is not a programming question, I am not sure even if its on-topic of other SE sites.

Comment: Please provide code with which you are getting the graph. Also details of the parameters vote_count and budget variables